# PHP cannot load memcache.so extension

Tags: php, memcached

I am trying to build and use PHP 5.5.3 with the memcache 2.2.6 PECL extension.  I'm building both from source on SUSE Linux.  They both make and install just fine, but the extension fails to load:

```
$ ./php -n -z path/to/memcache.so 
Failed loading path/to/memcache.so:  path/to/memcache.so: undefined symbol: php_session_create_id
$ readelf -s path/to//memcache.so | grep php_session_create_id
    19: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND php_session_create_id
   111: 0000000000000000     0 NOTYPE  GLOBAL DEFAULT  UND php_session_create_id
```

Some short background.  I was doing the same thing with PHP 8.2 and memcache 1.5 and it worked fine, but I want to upgrade to newer versions of both.

PHP build:

```
./configure --prefix="<php_location>"
        --with-apxs2="<path/to/apxs2>"
        --with-libxml-dir="<path/to/libxml2>"
        --with-xsl="<path/to/libxslt>"
        --with-zlib="<path/to/zlib>"
        --with-ncurses="<path/to/ncurses>"
        --with-ldap=shared,"<path/to/ldap>"
        --with-openssl=shared,"<path/to/openssl>"
        --with-curl=shared,"<path/to/curl>"
        --with-pgsql=shared,"<path/to/postgresql>"

        --with-config-file-path="<path/to/php.ini>"
        --with-layout=GNU
        --with-regex=php
        --with-tsrm-pthreads

        --disable-cgi
        --disable-rpath
        --disable-sysvsem
        --disable-sysvshm
        --disable-sysvmsg
        --disable-bcmath
        --disable-ctype
        --disable-exif
        --disable-spl
        --disable-ftp
        --disable-shmop
        --enable-tokenizer
        --enable-static

        --enable-memory-limit
        --enable-posix=shared
        --enable-session=shared
        --enable-sockets=shared
        --enable-xml=shared
        --enable-pcntl=shared
        --enable-soap
        --enable-dom

        --without-mm
        --without-gettext
        --without-iconv
        --without-sqlite
        --without-mime-magic
        --without-mysql
        --without-sybase-ct
        --without-gdbm
        --without-db4
        --without-cdb
        --without-inifile
        --without-flatfile
        --without-pear

        --disable-debug
        --with-pcre-dir="<path/to/pcre>"
        --with-pcre-regex


make
make install
```

memcache build:

```
./configure --enable-memcache
            --with-zlib-dir="<path/to/zlib>"
            --with-php-config="<path/to/php-config>"    # The one I just built

make
make install
```

Comment: Use your config files to ensure that session module is loaded before memcached ...

Comment: That was it!  Thanks Joe.

Comment: np ... it's not the fault of memcache ext by the way, php doesn't really have a good way of handling this kind of thing ...